# bad Make-Test while running installation of a perl module

Tags: opensuse, perl, make

i run opensuse 12,3  - all is installed fresh
now i wanted to install mozepl and www mechanize firefox

this ended up in a bad Make-Test while running installation of a perl module

```
        # '
        #     doesn't match '(?^:examples/open-local-file.pl syntax OK)'
        t/99-examples.t ................... 4/? 
        #   Failed test 'examples/bcat.pl compiles'
        #   at t/99-examples.t line 13.
        #                   'Can't locate MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/5.16.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib/Firefox/Application.pm line 4.
        # BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib/Firefox/Application.pm line 4.
        # Compilation failed in require at /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm line 12.
        # BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm line 12.
        # Compilation failed in require at examples/bcat.pl line 3.
        # BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at examples/bcat.pl line 3.
        # '
        #     doesn't match '(?^:examples/bcat.pl syntax OK)'




        ´t/select.t ........................ Can't locate MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/arch /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/5.16.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib/Firefox/Application.pm line 4.
        BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib/Firefox/Application.pm line 4.
        Compilation failed in require at /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm line 12.
        BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm line 12.
        Compilation failed in require at t/select.t line 6.
        BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/select.t line 6.
        t/select.t ........................ Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
        No subtests run 

        Test Summary Report
        -------------------
        t/00-load.t                     (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
          Failed test:  1
          Non-zero exit status: 1
        t/01-mech-destroy.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/47-mech-memleak2.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/47-mech-ref-memleak.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/47-mech-simplest.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/48-mech-launch.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/49-mech-get-file.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/49-mech-nav.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/49-mech-reuse.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-allow-js.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-app-new.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-app-profile.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-click.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-follow-link.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-form-with-fields.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-form2.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-load-and-load.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-activateTab.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-bufsize.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-closeTab.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-content.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-ct.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-encoding.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-error.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-event.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-forms.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-get-nocache.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-get.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-multi-event.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-new-dsl.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-new-with-tab.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-new.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-post.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-save-dialog.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-set-fields-875912.t   (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-mech-status.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-popup.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-rt65615.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/50-tick.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-click_button.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-click_js.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-form-number-blakew.t       (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-mech-field.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-mech-form-with-fields.t    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-mech-links.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-mech-navigation.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-mech-sandbox.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-mech-set-content.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/51-mech-submit.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/52-frame-document.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/52-frame-event.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/52-mech-api-find_link-frames.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/52-mech-api-find_link.t       (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/52-mech-xpath.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/52-selector-frames.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/52-selector-noframes.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/52-selector-relative.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/53-mech-capture-js-error.t    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/55-basic-auth.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/60-mech-cookies.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/60-mech-custom-headers.t      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/65-is_visible.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/65-mech-meta.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/65-set_visible.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/70-download-url.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/70-mech-png.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/70-real-status.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/70-rt70106-reload.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/70-rt71216.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/70-tag-team.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/70-two-instances.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/70-urlbar.t                   (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/75-save_url-cookies.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/99-changes.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 2 tests but ran 0.
        t/99-examples.t                 (Wstat: 3328 Tests: 14 Failed: 13)
          Failed tests:  1-4, 6-14
          Non-zero exit status: 13
        t/mechanize/autocheck.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/mechanize/content.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/rt65615.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/rt78706.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/rt84418.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        t/select.t                      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
          Non-zero exit status: 2
          Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
        Files=86, Tests=81,  7 wallclock secs ( 0.24 usr  0.10 sys +  5.38 cusr  0.73 csys =  6.45 CPU)
        Result: FAIL
        Failed 81/86 test programs. 14/81 subtests failed.
        make: *** [test_dynamic] Fehler 2
          /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/.
        one dependency not OK (MozRepl::RemoteObject); additionally test harness failed
          /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
        //hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
          reports /home/martin/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/.
        Running make install
          make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
        martin@linux-70ce:~/Downloads/perl/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74>

        - greetings dilbert ;-) - the first!

        Desktop: OpenSuse 11.4: Maxtor 160.0 GB, 2 GB
        Notebook: Akoya - P 6512 OpenSuse 12.1: AMD Athlon X2 P320, 2,10 GHz, 4 GB

    Edit / Delete Edit Post   Reply With Quote Reply With Quote     

+ Reply to Thread
« Previous Thread | Next Thread »
Tags for this Thread
Add / Edit Tags
None

View Tag Cloud
Bookmarks

    Submit to Digg Digg
    Submit to del.icio.us del.icio.us
    Submit to StumbleUpon StumbleUpon
    Submit to Google Google
    Submit to Facebook Facebook
    Submit to Twitter Twitter 

Posting Permissions

    You may post new threads
    You may post replies
    You may not post attachments
    You may edit your posts


    BB code is On
    Smilies are On
    [IMG] code is On
    [VIDEO] code is On
    HTML code is Off
    Trackbacks are On
    Pingbacks are On
    Refbacks are On

Forum Rules

    Contact Us
    openSUSE Forums
    Archive
    Privacy Statement
    Terms & Conditions
    Top

All times are GMT. The time now is 19:45.
© 2011 SUSE, All Rights Reserved.

Search Engine Friendly URLs by vBSEO 3.5.2 PL2
```

Comment: In general, when asking questions on Super User or anywhere else, I'd suggest very strongly that you follow the advice given [here](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html); doing so drastically improves your chances of getting a prompt and useful response.

Comment: And speaking of good advice: *don't* be [this](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly identifies the problem:

```
Can't locate MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm [...]
```

Have you installed the `MozRepl::RemoteObject` module? If not, do so, then retry whatever command elicited the output in your question.